# QR code generating but not working on device

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I haven't had any issues running our mini app on device in the past, but i have been experiencing issues from today where I upload our code, publish and generate a QR code successfully, however when trying to scan the QR code via the vodapay app to test on device it either just doesn't scan or the app crashes.

I have asked two other members in our team and they have the same experience. So that eliminates my device. Any pointers on what the issue might be?

Thanks

Comment: Try viewing your QR code with your phone or an online reader to see if it is valid

Comment: Thanks @Louis-JustinTallot found the issue, i was scanning the QR code from the "Scan to pay" funtion under the "Profile" tab instead of the "Pay" button on the landing page.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this is likely caused by the mini program size limit.

A few questions about this,
Which version of the IDE are you using?
Are you using IOS or Android devices?
How big is the mini program source code (not including the .log file)

The size limit is 12Mb so if the source code is larger than this it could be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TimothyBBD, it seems i was scanning the QR code from the wrong place within the Vodapay app, i navigated "Scan to pay" under the "Profile" tab instead of just clicking on the "Pay" button on the bottom of the navbar on the initial landing screen of the app.